# How to exclude an annotation from Kotlin AllOpen plugin?

Tags: kotlin, axon, kotlin-maven-plugin

I am using Axon Framework, where I can annotate my **domain** classes with `@Aggregate` (which is meta-annotated with @Component from Spring). Then I have to apologize for every private method/field I have by marking them `final` explicitly.

I think in my case I am good with just marking the class open, so I would like to do it manually while excluding `@Aggregate` from the `spring` plugin but I can't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

## workaround

According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#spring-support), the `spring` plugin uses `all-open` under the hood by just listing Spring annotations, while supporting the meta-annotating. So, we do exactly that, but we don't specify list `@Component`, so in our code, we must use the stereotypes (repository, service, etc.). This way it doesn't pick up the `@Aggregate`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <!-- instead of 'spring' -->
            <plugin>all-open</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
        <pluginOptions>
            <!-- todo check up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537496 -->
            <!-- listing all spring annotations except @Component -->
            <option>all-open:annotation=org.springframework.stereotype.Service</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=org.springframework.stereotype.Controller</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=org.springframework.data.repository.Repository</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async</option>
        </pluginOptions>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```